# How to get rid of new line character in a string, ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to remove the new line character in a string, I tried to use something like:

```
myString.replace('\n', '');
```

But this doesn't work. What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

A new string is returned, it is not modified in-place.

```
myString = myString.replace('\n', '');
```

If you have multiple newlines, you'll need to use a `RegExp` with the `g` flag set.

```
myString = myString.replace(new RegExp('\\n', 'g'), '');
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you don't want to use RegExp you can simply use split and join:
    `myString = myString.split('\n').join('');`